# How to find data on pivot table of a Many To Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Many To Many relationship between `users` & `wallets`.

So at the `User.php` Model:

```
public function wallets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');
    }
```

And at `Wallet.php` Model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id');
    }
```

And also the table Migration of `user_wallet` also goes here:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_wallet', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('usr_id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wallet_id');
            $table->foreign('wallet_id')->references('id')->on('wallets');
            $table->integer('balance');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Now I need to return a data based on it's User Id & Wallet Id, like this:

[image]

And at the Controller:

```
$bal = Wallet::where(['user_id' => $user_id, 'wallet_id' => $wallet_id]);
```

But this is wrong because the Model `Wallet` is connected to `wallets` table and not the pivot table which is `user_wallet`.

So how can I define `user_wallet` table for this `where` condition?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Per [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models), you may define pivot model then call it as `$userWalet = UserWalet::where(['user_id' => $userid, 'wallet_id' => $walletId])->first();`.

Comment: @Tpojka Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Wallet\UserWalet' not found

Comment: You need to make `UserWallet` model in location `app/Models/UserWallet.php` and import it in controller with `use App\Models\UserWallet`.

Comment: Edit: now I am checking that you are using version 5.8, in that case you don't have `Models` directory and your model will be in location `app/UserWallet.php` with import in controller with `use App\UserWallet` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use whereHas

```
Wallet::with("users")->whereHas('users',function ($query)use($user_id){

        $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
     

    })->find($wallet_id)
```

or

```
Wallet::with("users")->whereHas('users',function ($query)use($user_id,$wallet_id){

        $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
        $query->where('wallet_id',$wallet_id);

    })->first()
```

And also relationship need to be updated in wallet model

```
public function users() { 

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','wallet_id','user_id'); 
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it returns null, however the `user_id` and the `wallet_id` exists

Comment: look like relationship keys are wrong  so try public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','wallet_id','user_id');
    }